# Is the Google Kubernetes Engine cluster master IP static/fixed for the lifetime of the cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Do scenarios like master upgrade, master failover in a regional GKE cluster have potential to change the master endpoint IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GKE's master-node IP** is static and won't change unless explicitely [rotated](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-rotation) (see also: [rotating your cluster credentials](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/credential-rotation)). If you're asking if there is a guarantee that it will never change for the whole lifetime of the cluster, I didn't find such statement anywhere in [GKE docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs). So maybe there are some specific corner cases, when it can change, but as a general rule you can safely assume that it is static and doesn't change due to upgrades, failovers, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I was previously unaware of this documentation reference. This is the closest evidence I've seen in the official documentation that provides an indication that explicit action may need to be taken to effect a change in the cluster endpoint IP. Quote from the doc: "Note: The master IP address is static and does not change unless an IP rotation is initiated."